# C++ 11 noncopyable class

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any class similar to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/noncopyable.hpp introduced by C++ 11? I can't use `= delete` feature as my compiler doesn't support it. I would prefer to use standard library features if possible instead of boost or implementing my own.

Comment: You could just create a private copy constructor and assignment operator like in C++03.

Comment: @KennyTM Yes, but this will force me to have a default constructor and sometimes I don't want one...

Comment: Boost.noncopyable also introduced a (protected) default c'tor if you check the source...

Comment: @KennyTM Yes, that is a very convenient way of making an object non copyable. I just wanted to know if there is something like this in the standard.

Comment: Considering how small `noncopyable` is...

Comment: "*I just wanted to know if there is something like this in the standard*" that is exactly what `= delete` is.  It is not the standard's fault that your compiler is not up-to-date.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there is no similar standard class. C++11 introduced `= delete` for this purpose, so additionally introducing a class would have been needlessly redundant and useless.

Answer (score 4):

i don't think noncopyable is useless. The '= delete' need to be used twice (copy ctor and assignment operator) and that would be too much typing.
if your code already has dependency on boost - the use of boost::noncopyable is preferred.